# EF Core Compound key auto_increment secondary column

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core

Basically I want something like this:

```
+----+------+-----+
| Id | Name | Ver |
+----+------+-----+
| 1  | Foo  | 1   |
| 2  | Foo  | 2   |
| 3  | Bar  | 1   |
| 4  | Baz  | 1   |
+----+------+-----+
```

Each object has assigned versions. Version numbers are auto incremented by DB. Naturally for each new versioned object, version number needs to reset to 1.

I've tried:

```
u.HasKey(x => x.Id);
u.HasKey(x => new { x.Name, x.Ver } );
u.Property(x => x.Ver)
    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
```

and

```
u.HasKey(x => new { x.Name, x.Ver, x.Id } );
```

and variations thereof.

Nothing seems to give me what I want. Any time I add a new named entry, `Ver` just keeps incrementing.

Comment: It is not possible. Value generation happens in 2 ways in EF Core. Either you provide a client value generator or you set up database to generate values. If you can think of how to configure your database to auto increment but reset at new version name then let us know. I can provide how to configure database for that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a trigger that sets the version to a Count(*) of existing rows? Also, when versioning... is it really necessary that the version numbers follow precisely? If there are gaps, that shouldn't really be a problem I think. If you want to know if a row has a later or earlier version, just check for a row with version number greater than or smaller than.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is what I will end up doing. Would still like to know if there is a code only solution to this though :)

Comment: In EF you can intercept Updates and Inserts in your code before they are sent to the database. You could potentionally update the field there. I would advise against that though, because of concurrencly issues where you will end up with rows with the same version number because different apps were writing to the table at exactly the same time.